# Does a regex try to match agains the positions between characters in the text?

Tags: regex, linux, perl

I had the idea that when matching a regex only the characters of the text are matched. But then I saw this:

```
$ perl -e '  
my $var = "abcde";   
$var =~ s/x?/!/g;  
print "$var\n";  
'  
!a!b!c!d!e!
```

The way I understand this is that the regex is attempted to be matched against the characters **and** the nothingness in the indexes between the characters. Is this correct? Or else how come we get the exclamations between the characters?

Comment: The quantifier `?` can match 0 or 1 time, so it will match the empty string if it can. You have to be careful with such quantifiers.

Comment: *every* match starts and ends at positions *between* characters (or the start and end of the string), not *on* characters.

Comment: @ysth:I don't understand this statement.Which is the index of the position *between* the characters?

Comment: in the string "abc", there are four positions, 0 through 3.  0 precedes the a, 1 is between a and b, etc.  does that help?

Comment: @ysth:"0 precedes the a, 1 is between a and b, etc" This is a "view" we have for the regex.But when indexing a string or array I don't see which index is between a and b. Index i is of a character.

Comment: no, indexing a string works exactly the same, e.g. `$x="abc"; substr($x,1,0)="def"` gives adefbc; if an index were a character rather than between characters, a zero length would never make sense (or at least would be ambiguous over whether it came before or after the character)

Comment: @ysth:But in your example, `d` is inserted in index 1 replacing `b` which is shifted and so on.It is not between a and b.Perhaps this is a conceptual view of the regex and not an implementation view?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is a useful way to think about it. More formally, we can imagine *any* string containing a zero-length substring at any position:

```
'' eq '' . ''
'foo' eq '' . 'f' . '' . 'o' . '' . 'o' . ''
```

The regex `/x?/` tries to match `x`, or the zero-length string. It's equivalent to `/x|/`. Note that a regex that always succeeds looks like `/(?=)/` (look-ahead to see a zero-length string), because `//` is special-cased to repeat the last match, unless when used in `split //, ...` to split after each character.

The match will nevertheless move forward one character in order to avoid an infinite loop: `split //, "foo"` produces `'f', 'o', 'o'` and not `'', '', '', ..., 'f', 'o', 'o'`

Comment: split is special in several ways (one of which is discarding leading zero-width matches); http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=322751 may be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Regex matches are expressed in terms of starting position and end position, which is to say starting position and length.

```
$ perl -E'say "pos:$-[0] len:".($+[0]-$-[0]) while "abcde" =~ /x?/g;'
pos:0 len:0
pos:1 len:0
pos:2 len:0
pos:3 len:0
pos:4 len:0
pos:5 len:0
```

It's not so much matching in between as replacing zero characters at each position.

(It would an infinite number of times at position 0 if there wasn't a rule preventing the matching the same number of characters at the same position twice. This forces the engine to look at other positions until all positions are exhausted.)

(There's a virtual position at the end of the string so `$` and `\z` can match.)

Comment: So the fact that `len` is 0 at a specific position is not taken into consideration when trying to verify if we got a match at that position? And then the elements are shifted so as to accommodate the replacing element?

Comment: Correct, it's perfectly valid to match a string of length zero. It happens all the time (e.g. `"ac" =~ /ab*c/` is true because `b*` matched 0 chars at position 1.) Except to check if you repeating the same match (same pos and same length), the length isn't checked. // I guess you could say that, but then you have to say that `@-` and `@+` refer to the original positions. It view it as building a new string from the unmatched text and replacement text (which I'm pretty sure is actually what happens).

Comment: `It would an infinite number of times at position 0 if there wasn't a rule preventing...` Why would it stuck?Because it would use the offset to move which is 0 in this case?

Comment: Because it normally starts matching where it left off, so the first time it matches 0 chars at pos 0. Then it matches matches 0 chars at pos 0. Then it matches matches 0 chars at pos 0. Then it...

Comment: No idea what offset you're talking about.

Comment: @Jim: "Why would it stuck?" because using Mohith's code as an example, if it weren't explicitly disallowed, that could would endlessly print "Before: 0\nInside: 0\nAfter: 0\nDone: 0\nBefore: 0\nInside: 0\nAfter: 0\nDone: 0\n...".  From that example, you can see it does try to match a second time at each position, but rejects it and advances in the string and retries matching from the beginning of the regex

Comment: @ikegami:In your answer you mention `pos` and `len`.I assume that this `len` is used as an offset to move in the text.That way it would get stuck since the offset (i.e. pos+len) would be 0 constantly

Comment: I derived len, so it's definitely not use to offset anything, but yes, pos+len does show the position from where matching will resume.

Answer (score 2):

As ikegami points out in his answer, each position before/between/after the characters are valid positions of the beginning of a match. In your example, the matches start at each possible position and span a length of 0, so each 0-length match gets replaced with a 1-length `'!'`.

Internally, the `$var` maintains a position that the regex engine uses to track its progress while doing the substitution. This position represents the index of the "nothingness" before/between/after the characters. To help visualize this position, here is the same code snippet with various print statements (of the position of `$var`) inserted throughout the regex.

```
$ perl -e 'my $var = "abcde";
$var =~ s/(?{ print "Before: ", pos, "\n" })
          (?:
            (?{ print "Inside: ", pos, "\n" })
            x
            (?{ print "Never: ", pos, "\n" })
          )?
          (?{ print "After: ", pos, "\n" })
         / print "Done: ", pos, "\n\n"; "!" /gex;
print "$var\n";
'
```

The output of the above is:

```
Before: 0
Inside: 0
After: 0
Done: 0

Before: 0
Inside: 0
After: 0
Before: 1
Inside: 1
After: 1
Done: 1

Before: 1
Inside: 1
After: 1
Before: 2
Inside: 2
After: 2
Done: 2

Before: 2
Inside: 2
After: 2
Before: 3
Inside: 3
After: 3
Done: 3

Before: 3
Inside: 3
After: 3
Before: 4
Inside: 4
After: 4
Done: 4

Before: 4
Inside: 4
After: 4
Before: 5
Inside: 5
After: 5
Done: 5

Before: 5
Inside: 5
After: 5
!a!b!c!d!e!
```

I'm not sure why the `Before`, `Inside`, and `After` sections are executed twice per position. My guess is that the regex engine is able to detect an infinite loop (as ikegami and amon point out), so it avoids matching those positions the second time it encounters them.

Comment: yes, there is a special rule that a zero-width match is not allowed if the previous match was a zero-width match at the same position.  so it succeeds in matching the entire regex with no x, then notices that wasn't allowed and tries again one character further into the string.

Answer (score 0):

I will say that the pattern matches an empty string at each position in the string.

Comment: `perl -e 'my $var = "abcde";$var =~ s//!/g;print "$var\n";'` also gives `!a!b!c!d!e!` (since we are matching those empty string). Is this behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: @Matt: Perhaps, but i really don't know where. But note that this is a logical behaviour.

Comment: @Matt: be very careful there; // in substitution or matching means use the last (dynamically scoped) successful  rexex, or an empty regex if there was none. `perl -we 'my $var = "abcde"; "x"=~/x/; $var =~ s//!/g;print "$var\n";'` prints 'abcde'.  use `/(?#)/` for a truly empty match.

Comment: @Matt: your behavior doesn't need to be documented as a special case; it is implicitly true from what is documented (though the documentation does discuss zero-length/zero-width matches explicitly in several places).

Comment: @ysth that makes sense. It seems like if there isn't a last regex it will use nothing though. Thanks!